# How can templates replicate dynamic polymorphism when behaviour can be different?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism

I have heard templates can be used to replicate dynamic polymorphism through static polymorphism. If this is the case I am puzzled how it works.

I thought the purpose of templates was to replicate the exact same behaviour, but across different classes. In contract dynamic polymorphism allows you to call the exact same API (which can have **different behaviour** in the functions) for different classes? If there is different behaviour across the objects, how can templates achieve this??

Comment: You're asking us to comment on something *you've heard*? Why don't you ask whoever told you that what they meant?

Comment: Do you have any references? As far as I know, templates are strictly compile-time tools. "Polymorphism" can be achieved using dispatch tables without templates, though using templates can "automate" the process to some extent...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example :

```
template <typename T>
class logger
{
  public:

  void log(const std::string& str)
  {
    this->_interface.kindof_virtual_method_without_runtime_cost(str);
  }

  private:

  T _interface;
};

class on_console{...};
class on_network{...};

int main(void)
{
  logger<on_console> logger_console;
  logger<on_network> logger_network;

  logger_console.log("debug");
  logger_network.log("release");

  return 0;
}
```

---

> I thought the purpose of templates was to replicate the exact same behaviour, but across different classes. In contract dynamic polymorphism allows you to call the exact same API (which can have **different behaviour** in the functions) for different classes

As you can see in the example above, it is a template that allows you to call the exact same API (the "kindof_virtual_method_without_runtime_cost" member function) which can have diffrent behaviour for different classes

This is probably what was meant by

> replicate dynamic polymorphism through static polymorphism

Of course this does not apply to situations dependent on runtime conditions (user input etc..), the polymorphisme branch must be known at compile time

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a special usage of the CTRP c++ idiom that can replace, in some cases, dynamic polymorphism with a static one.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism